# Django Separate Settings raises error TemplateDoesNotExist at /

Tags: django

I have been attempting to separate my settings via settings folder with base, dev prod and init files and ran the server with the dev settings it says it runs with no issues but when I click on the link I now get an error TemplateDoesNotExist at /, I was able to access the page before seperating my settings

I decided to try the above on a fresh django project which appears to have worked on out of the box django main page and admin panel however again when I go to add a new url and view and template the same error is raised TemplateDoesNotExist at /.

Please see the following code exlcuding settings/base.py as this is just fresh project settings but cut SECRET_KEY and placed in settings/dev.py which worked prior to adding url/view and template:

**urls**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include, reverse_lazy
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views
from . import views


urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', views.home, name="home"),
]
```

**views**

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect

def home(request):
    return render(request, 'test.html')
```

**template - projectroot/templates/test.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Test</title>
</head>

<h1>Test</h1>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

Help is much apprecaited in getting this back runing again. Thanks

Comment: i think you need to include a template inside your template directory inside new settings

Comment: Please give some more info. The error message means django can not find your test.html. If this message only appears once you seperate settings.py into base + dev/prod I would first check if dev or prod are really included. If yes, then please post the content.

Comment: It is important to check if the view works without the seperation as this is not 100% clear from your description. If with a single settings.py the view also causes an error, then in general there is a problem with the path to your test.html. in that case we would need the folder structure of your project as well as the TEMPLATES definition in settings.py

Comment: @MohamedBeltagy Thanks a lot for this, you put me on the right path as my settings had moved to a new directory my BASE_DIR needed changing I'll update the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aplogies if i was not clear enough, but i manage dtor esolve the issue as per Mohamed Beltagy's answer, as the settings files had move up a level to a new settings folder the issue was with the default BASE_DIR being as:

```
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent
```

and had to change to as folows:

```
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent.parent
```